# jQuery validation for with label color change

Tags: jquery

Can some one help me with jQuery validation code sample with text label color change, when form validation fails the label color change to red.

I need to create a form with multiple field,when the required field validation form validation fails, the form field label are supposed to change red, I am new to jQuery, can someone help me?

Comment: the first 2 links in google search by request "jquery validation sample code" brought me these links: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ and http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/ - both answer your question almost fully

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is a bit vague... however here is a small implementation of how to check for empty values on a textfield using jquery and change their color depending of the existence of user input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").click(function(){
        var textInput = $('#textfield').val();

      if (textInput === "") {
        $('#textfield').css('background', 'red');
      }
      else {
        $('#textfield').css('background', 'green');
      }
   })
})
```

Check the html here and see how it works. Hope it helps
https://fiddle.jshell.net/PatoSalazarC/28t2mjkp/

Answer (score 0):

The following will do exactly what you asked for. let me know if you have any questions. Cheers!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sets up validation for a form, then checks if the form is valid when clicking a button.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
    <label id="myLabel" >First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="name" required>
  <br>
  <button type="button">Validate!</button>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
var form = $("#myform");
form.validate();
$("button").click(function () {
    if (form.valid() != true) {
        $("#myLabel").css("color", "red");
    }
});
// Change text "First Name" back to black when user types into textbox
$("#name").keyup(function () {
    $("#myLabel").css("color", "black");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your support.how can avoid the statement 'This field is required' , i just want to change only the label color when the form validation occurs(required field)

Comment: Here is the .click event changed up a bit to more meet your needs. You can play around with this to get what you want.$("button").click(function () {
    if ($("#name").val() == "") {
        $("#myLabel").css("color", "red");
    }
});